# Is there a way to delete history in Firefox 11 over a certain age?

Tags: firefox, privacy, history

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I delete everything in my Firefox history older than N days?](https://superuser.com/questions/15794/how-can-i-delete-everything-in-my-firefox-history-older-than-n-days)

Say I want to delete browsing history over a month old in Firefox, is there a way to do that without clearing out my entire browsing history?

Comment: Here's the thing, that question and it's answers are out of date by three years. Newer versions of Firefox work differently then the version those answers were directed to. Out of date Q&A is a major issue with all stackexchange sites and I feel that that alone is reason to keep this question open. Would it be helpful if I specified what version of Firefox this question pertains to?

Comment: The above comment is directed @random, in regards to the closing of the question.

Comment: The answers on that other question might be out of date, but the question isn't. It allows for any version of Firefox. Yours may/will be outdated given their rapid release cycles now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try out this firefox addon :

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/expire-history-by-days/